# Elastic search gives same result only in alternate queries

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I'm facing an issue while working with elastic search. While searching with same query on the same data, the ES returns same **_meta.score** (of the results) only on the alternate calls. That is, if the **_meta.score** of the result is 'A' on the first call, it returns 'B' on the second call, 'A' on the third call, 'B' on the fourth call and so on.
I'm using PyES wrapper in python.

Following is the setting I've for PyES

```
SETTINGS = {"index": {
"analysis": {"char_filter": {"my_mapping": {
"type": "mapping", "mappings": ["\\u0091=>\\u0027", "\\u0092=>\\u0027",
                                "\\u2018=>\\u0027", "\\u2019=>\\u0027",
                                "\\u201B=>\\u0027"]}},
                                "filter": {"english_stop": {
                                "type": "stop", "stopwords": "_english_"}},
                                "analyzer": {"wsplusstop": {
                                "type": "custom",
                                "char_filter": "my_mapping",
                                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                                "filter": ["lowercase", "english_stop",
                                "porter_stem"]}}}}}
```

Comment: Can you please show your query code too?

Comment: I'm using PyES wrapper and the query is actually an object (of type pyes.query.BoolQuery). The process and data used to create this query is the same for every call.